Geometry Nodes - how to "move" object from Object Info node to 3d viewport?
Here's a simple example - I have a scene with a Cube and a Sphere, then I add a Geo Nones modifier to the Cube, to which I add the Sphere in the "Object Info" node.
Let's say I accidentally delete the Sphere from the 3d Viewport and save the file.
What's the easiest way to have the Sphere in the 3d Viewport again, which is contained in the "Object Info" node?
Thx.
Edit - adding screenshots


Not enough information! Please add a screenshot of your Geometry Nodes workspace so that we can see what you're talking about. In Blender, Window > Save Screenshot then  edit your question and add the image it produces into it.

Screenshot added.

I don't think it's possible. You'll have to add another torus into the viewport at the same location and size as the one you deleted and set the Object Info node name to that of the torus you've just added.

The only way to "delete" an object so that it keeps in scene is "unlink". In this case, change Outliner to Blender File mode

then drag and drop unlinked object to one of the collections:


I probably did not describe my question precisely, I added a screenshot to the post.

Doesn't matter, answer is the same
